# how to create a view from multiple select statements in same mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

Please bear me if this is annoying you all.

I have 6 queries in my page.All the queries are run in same mysql table but with different where clauses.

Currently I execute those queries one by one.But I need to combine those sql queries to single view or single query to display records according to `material_id`.

queries are follows,

```
$a_recieved="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity-damage_quantity-returned_quantity) AS re_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS re_total_price,SUM(purchase_quantity) AS re_total_purchase FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Recieved'";

$a_purchased="SELECT material_id,SUM(purchase_quantity) AS total_p FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Purchase'"));

$a_production="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS pr_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS pr_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Production'";

$a_fg="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS fg_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS fg_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Fgoods'";

$a_returned="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS rt_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS rt_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Return'";

$a_transfered="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS tr_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS tr_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Transfer'";
```

I am sorry this may not the efficient way to do this though.

Is there any possibility to do these in single query? or do I have to use mysql Views for this? If so please advise me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Can anyone post a proper answer for my issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your 6 queries return same number of columns, and same kind of data (ie. always ID, Quantity, Total Price) then you case use one single query with `UNION`.

```
 SELECT 'Received' as Operation, id, quantity, price FROM table1
 UNION
 SELECT 'Purchased', id, quantity, price FROM table2
 UNION
 ...
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer But number of columns are to be different in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$query="SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity-damage_quantity-returned_quantity) AS re_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS re_total_price,SUM(purchase_quantity) AS re_total_purchase FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Recieved'
UNION
SELECT material_id,SUM(purchase_quantity) AS total_p FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Purchase'
UNION
SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS pr_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS pr_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Production'
UNION
SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS fg_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS fg_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Fgoods'
UNION
SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS rt_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS rt_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Return'
UNION
SELECT material_id,SUM(recieved_quantity) AS tr_total_quantity,SUM(each_price) AS tr_total_price FROM purchase_table WHERE material_id='".$info['material_id']."' AND added_time<NOW() AND item_status='Transfer'";
```

use the UNION function of SQL.
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

sorry, can't verify the result if it is what you want, though.
but maybe you can find a way around.